Automator Quick Action to duplicate "Copy Link" in the service menu?
I open www.themoviedb.org and search for a movie. The webpage has a tab called "Media" that contains thumbnail links to cover art images. If I click a thumbnail it opens the target file in Safari. I want to open it in Preview. If I right-click and choose "Copy Link" it will copy the image URL to the clipboard. I then have a program that grabs the link from the clipboard and does what I want with it. But I have to use "Copy Link" and then run my program (or leave it running in the background) to get the URL. I would like to make an Automator Quick Action called "get-it". So I can right-click the thumbnail, select "get-it", and the Quick Action gets the URL and then runs more processes on it. Here lies the REAL problem. Every Quick Action I have tried only shows up in the Services Menu if the URL is a hypertext link, or the image is already selected. I can't pre-select the image/link or it takes me to the full image in Safari. If I right-click the image/link my Quick Action doesn't show up in the Services Menu. I need to duplicate exactly what "Copy Link" does, but in an Automator workflow, so I can add processes to the workflow. If this is confusing, go to the page I listed, find any movie, right-click on one of the cover-art pictures, and select "Copy Link". I need a Quick Action to duplicate the results of that.
By the way, my current solution is this: First I start a program I wrote in BASIC (compiled to C++). It watches the clipboard for anything starting with "http" and ending with an image file extension. If it sees something it uses a shell command with cURL to retrieve the image, saves it to a temp folder, then launches Preview and loads the image. But I have to start the program first, use "Copy Link" for the image, then end it when I'm done with the images. I want to re-write it so when I use "get-it" it gets the URL, does what my BASIC program does, then exits without having to use multiple clicks or open/close other programs.
By the way, "Copy Image" and "Copy Image Address" work the same way.
